# Hibernate SaveOrUpdate based on attributes not in auto-generated primary-key

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

Hibernate bases the decision as to whether to perform an update or save on the uniqueness of the primary-key.  This works great if you query the database and load a previously auto-generated primary-key.  But what if in ETL a new entity is created but it is really just a duplicate of what is in the database already.  Can Hibernate be instructed to perform an Update instead of a Save?

For instance, I load several XML files describing products and associated product categories.   Each XML file describes a unique product but the categories are just repeats of what is already in the database in the CATAGORIES table.  Let’s say, name = CAT1, CAT2 or CAT3.  But when I create instances of the POJO class entities for both Products and Category upon parsing the XML files, Category has a new and distinct auto-generated primary-key, but it is still either a CAT1, CAT2 or CAT3.  But Hibernate performs a Save as the identifier is unique.  But I wanted an Update.  If a new say CAT4 is loaded, then I would want a Save.

Can Hibernate use a unique-key other than the generated primary-key as the identifier in making the SaveOrUpdate decision?  And without precluding use of the auto-generated primary-key functionality?

Comment: I think you can't you will have to implement your own saveOrUpdate, that not too hard, make a select based on your restriction if result update() else save().